# Already have MSDN with Team System Test edition, how do I

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

Already have MSDN with Team System Test Edition, how do I go about getting Developer Edition?  Can't find it on MSDN.

Do I need to buy a whole other MSDN license for this?

Can you add just another SKU into the Team System family, in other words, can you have 2 Team System Versions, or does it have to be the Team $uite MegaVersion or single versions?

Also, can you use FxCop with the nice VS shell integration inside of VS Test Edition?

Any URLs/hints would be greatly appreciated.  Seems to me that there's very little documentation on how to mix and match VS versions.  Would be great if MSFT had a "Visual Studio store" MENU ITEM in VS where you could go and just buy/download the different SKUs automatically.  I mean it takes me just a few clicks to download extra states into TurboTax, but MSFT makes that very hard to do.

P.S. Same set of questions for Visual Studio Database Edition.....yes I'm a dev that wears many hats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 common levels of licensing that you see:

**Visual Studio Pro** - Doesn't include any of the team system features

**Visual Studio Team System xxxxx Edition** - Where xxxx is either Developer, Tester, Architect or DBPro.  Includes all the functionality of VS Pro + the functionality associated with the role you chose.

**Visual Studio Team Suite** - Includes the functionality of all the different role editions.

If you have the VSTS Developer Edition and you want some of the functionality from the other roles, you either have to buy a 2nd VSTS license for the other role, or upgrade to VSTS Team Suite.  If I remember correctly VSTS Team Suite is about twice the cost of a specific role version of VSTS, so rather than purchasing multiple role editions most people just opt to upgrade to Team Suite since the cost is approx. the same.

You can compare the list prices here: http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/howtobuy/compare-price.mspx

Answer (score 0):

First, once you logon to the MSDN site, make sure you've clicked the "Downloads" tab at the top of the page, and then near the lower-right click on "MSDN Subscriber Downloads". Software that you have access to at your level of subscription will appear in the list.

Second, you may consider reviewing the details of your level of MSDN subscription if you still don't see what you're looking for.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you will really be using all the different products, then it is best to have the full System license. I think 2 of the products make the price of the full, if you are using 3 ...

Comment: My 2 year MSDN subscription cost me about ~$1400.  I understand the Team Suite is roughly $5K.  That's a BIG JUMP in price for the suite.

Comment: http://shopper.cnet.com/databases/microsoft-visual-studio-team/4014-3553_9-32746038.html 3000-3300 ... if you are buying 3, you are better buying an upgrade (dunno if there is one though)

Comment: pricing is just weird, you got yours for that price: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/subscriptionschart.aspx ... if this link were the price, it would have cost 5000 ...